# Почему в python tcp и udp сокеты имеют разный laddr?

Tags: python, сокет, tcp, udp

Пишу приложение-игру, в которой обмен данными (по типу логин, пароль, прочая информация о пользователе) между клиентом и сервером проходит по протоколу tcp, а сам игровой процесс по udp.
Тестирую в домашней сети через один вайфай.
Когда пытаюсь подключить сокеты по udp, выдает ошибку подключения. Пытаясь разобраться в чем дело, заметил что у сокетов на сервере разные локальные адреса.

```
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind('',8080)
```

laddr=('192.168.1.106',8080)

Выдает IPv4 устройства, тут все понятно и работает

```
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind('',8081)
```

laddr=('0.0.0.0',8081)

От тут я немного удивился, не могу понять откуда взялись ноли и какой адрес для подключения вводить со стороны клиента. Клиент запущен на другом устройстве, но в той же локальной сети.

Comment: Где и как вы смотрите laddr? У питонового сокета такого атрибута нет, а `sock.getsockname()` для tcp выдаёт у меня `('0.0.0.0', 8080)` как мной и ожидалось

Comment: через ```print(sock)``` принтуются все его атрибуты

Comment: Принт у меня тоже выводит 0.0.0.0 как и ожидалось https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQQOP.png

Comment: только что посмотрел и понял, что сокет, использующий tcp меняет laddr после приминения метода ```sock.listen(1)```. Только от по udp данный метод не предусмотрен. И пытаюсь понять на какой адрес отправлять данные с клиента, так как при попытке отправить на '192.168.1.106' выдает ошибку подключения

Comment: У меня listen ничего не меняет, всё такой же 0.0.0.0 как и должен быть https://i.stack.imgur.com/edQC3.png

Comment: Вообще нули означают "любой адрес данного устройства". Так что вводить любой из адресов севера, например тот же 192.168.1.106 (если это адрес сервера). И что такое "ошибка подключения" для протокола UDP. В этом протоколе нет понятия "подключение". Вы просто сразу посылаете пакеты на нужный адрес и порт, с помощью sendto